# SOA/BPEL query "/p:input" is invalid, because step 'p:input" is invalid

Tags: soa, bpel

I am new to SOA/BPEL, and I follow a tutorial in the book and try to create a simple SOA application, but when I try to deploy my following code in to weblogic server, I got following error:

```
Error(73): query "/p:input" is invalid, because step 'p:input' is not valid.
Error(75): query "/p:result/ p:message" is invalid, because step 'p:result' is not valid.
```

What I doing wrong?

Here is the bpel process code

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<process name="BPELProcess1"
         targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SOATutorial1/Project1/BPELProcess1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
         xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SOATutorial1/Project1/BPELProcess1"
         xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
         xmlns:bpelx="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"
         xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
         xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
         xmlns:bpel2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
         xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
         xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
         xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
         xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
         xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
         xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
         xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap">
  <!-- 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        PARTNERLINKS                                                      
        List of services participating in this BPEL process               
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    -->
  <partnerLinks>
    <!-- 
      The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. It is 
      used for callback. The location and correlation information associated
      with the client role are automatically set using WS-Addressing.
    -->
    <partnerLink name="bpelprocess1_client"
                 partnerLinkType="client:BPELProcess1"
                 myRole="BPELProcess1Provider"/>
  </partnerLinks>
  <variables>
    <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
    <variable name="inputVariable"
              messageType="client:BPELProcess1RequestMessage"/>
    <!-- Reference to the message that will be returned to the requester-->
    <variable name="outputVariable"
              messageType="client:BPELProcess1ResponseMessage"/>
  </variables>

  <sequence name="main">
    <!-- Receive input from requestor. (Note: This maps to operation defined in BPELProcess1.wsdl) -->
    <receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="bpelprocess1_client"
             portType="client:BPELProcess1" operation="process"
             variable="inputVariable" createInstance="yes"/>
    <assign name="Assign1">
      <copy>
        <from expression="concat('BPEL working ', bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable', 'payload', '/p:input'))"/>
        <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
            query="/p:result/ p:message"/>
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
    <reply name="replyOutput" partnerLink="bpelprocess1_client"
           portType="client:BPELProcess1" operation="process"
           variable="outputVariable"/>
  </sequence>
</process>
```

I am using SOA 11.1.1.6 version, and I already tried to search on google, and I realize my syntax is actually is same as what they provided, is it any namespace I missing or what?